# Laravel filters won't work when trying to add them

Tags: php, html, laravel

So I'm making a fliter in laravel for a project and me and my teacher are braking our head on a the following thing.

In the code below the general search for a player works but the other statements won't add to it if they are defined and in the POST request;

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class FilterController extends Controller
{
    public function filter(Request $request)
    {
      $player = new \App\Player;
      $filters = $player->newQuery();
      $query = Input::get('q');

      // Search for a player based on their status.
      if ($request->has('status')) {
        $filters->orwhere('status', $request->input('status'));
      }
      // Search for a player player on their club.
      if ($request->has('club')) {
        $filters->orwhere('Club', $request->input('club'));
      }
      // Search for a player player on their team category .
      if ($request->has('Category')) {
        $filters->orwhere('Category', $request->input('Category'));
      }
      // Search for a player player if he is flagged as removed.
      if ($request->has('remove')) {
       $filters->orwhere('remove', $request->input('remove'));
      }
      // Search for a player player on their size.
      if ($request->has('size')) {
        $filters->orwhere('Size', $request->input('size'));
      }

      // General search for a player
      if($request->has('q')){
        $filters->orwhere('first_name','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
        ->orWhere('last_name','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
        ->orWhere('mobile','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
        ->orWhere('street_name_nummer','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
        ->orWhere('city','LIKE','%'.$query.'%');
      }
      // Get the results and return them.

      $results = $filters->get();

      if(count($results) > 0){
        return view('lists/ekick')->withDetails($results,$query);
      } else return view ('lists/ekick')->with('No Details found. Try to search again !');
    }
}
```

route:

```
Route::any('lists/ekick', 'FilterController@filter');
```

output view:

[img from view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nfuh.png)

Comment: can you add a `dd($request)` result to the question?

Comment: I will put some screenshots in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pick up on Aaron Sarays answer, you are most likely filtering the wrong way. Normally additional filters are additional conditions each record has to meet in order to be part of the result. If you consider an Excel table and you filter one column, you won't even have all options to filter for in the second column because you already limited the result and you can only limit it further.

Combine this knowledge with an improved way of filtering and you receive a query like this:

```
public function filter(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->input('q');

    $results = \App\Player::query()
        ->when($request->input('status'), function ($query, $status) {
            $query->where('status', $status);
        })
        ->when($request->input('club'), function ($query, $club) {
            $query->where('club', $club);
        })
        ->when($request->input('category'), function ($query, $category) {
            $query->where('category', $category);
        })
        ->when($request->input('remove'), function ($query, $remove) {
            $query->where('remove', $remove);
        })
        ->when($request->input('size'), function ($query, $size) {
            $query->where('size', $size);
        })
        ->when($query, function ($query, $q) {
            $query->where(function ($query) use ($q) {
                $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', "%$q%")
                    ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', "%$q%")
                    ->orWhere('mobile', 'LIKE', "%$q%")
                    ->orWhere('street_name_number', 'LIKE', "%$q%")
                    ->orWhere('city', 'LIKE', "%$q%");
            });
        })
        ->get();

    if ($results->isNotEmpty()) {
        return view('lists/ekick')->withDetails($results, $query);
    } else {
        return view ('lists/ekick')->with('No Details found. Try to search again !');
    }
}
```

The function `when($condition, $callback)` as used in the query above is used to dynamically build queries. You can consider the following two statements equivalent:

```
// option 1: conditional query (preferred!)
$results = Player::query()
    ->when($request->input('q'), function ($query, $q) {
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$q%");
    })
    ->get();

// option 2: plain php query building... (not very clean code)
$query = Player::query();

if ($request->input('q')) {
    $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->input('q').'%');
}

$results = $query->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to do what you're doing, I think you want to not use `or` with your queries.  You're basically saying

> Give me the Player where status is something or size is something

I think what you mean to say is

> Give me the Player where status is something and size is something

Depending on if the requirements exist or not in the filter.

So, you'd want to alter your code using the following as an example:

```
if ($request->has('status')) {
  $filters->where('status', $request->input('status'));
}
// Search for a player player on their club.
if ($request->has('club')) {
  $filters->where('Club', $request->input('club'));
}
```

You can also bypass one step by using this:

```
$query = \App\Player::getQuery();
```

Comment: @wardpille - this part `if($request->has('q')){` needs to be an exclusive or.  I don't use laravel but it should be in parentheses in the SQL, so  `this = ? AND ( first_name LIKE %$q% OR last_name LIKE %$q% OR ... )`  That way the OR is evaluated as a group.  IF you dont do that you are saying `this = ? AND  first_name LIKE %$q% OR last_name LIKE %$q% OR ... ` this and first name like q OR last name like q...  In other words if last name is like q then none of the ANDs would matter.

Comment: no i doesn't have to be but that line works fin it the other if statements i have some trouble

Comment: No succes stil not applying the other filters the search works but the others not.